# What technology should i use for streaming tweets and analysis?

Tags: twitter, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to stream live tweets from twitter API and then analyse them. I should use kafka to get tweets or spark streaming directly or both ?

Comment: The data throughput from Twitter's Streaming API is not very high. No extra streaming technology is required in order to process tweets.

Comment: @Jonas i need tweets for Sentiment Analysis
So what technologies should i use ?

Comment: I posted a direction you may want to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kafka Connect to ingest tweets, and then Kafka Streams or KSQL to analyse them. Check out [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-ksql-to-analyse-query-and-transform-data-in-kafka) here which describes exactly this.

Comment: The size of tweets is not too high that's why i can use directly spark streaming ? no ? or i have to use  kafka for durability ?

Comment: If you're using Kafka, using Kafka Streams or KSQL makes the integration much simpler. You can use Spark Streaming if you want - it's up to you.

Comment: For those downvoting this answer: please leave a comment so that I can understand what is not useful/appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language of choice I would use one of the libraries listed here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries. Which ever you choose, you will be using `statuses/filter` in the Twitter API, so get familiar with the doc here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html

Comment: I am using scala